# pass data from login controller to login.blade.php in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6

I am trying to pass data from  login controller to login.blade.php in laravel 6 like I using common header throughout the application so I have to create dynamic title and description. default login controller is something like this

```
class LoginController extends Controller
{

 protected $redirectTo = RouteServiceProvider::HOME;


public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
}
}
```

Don't know how to pass. please help

Comment: where is your login function where your are loading your login blade file

Comment: Its full logincontroller file which i shared... i am new to laravel...

Comment: did you installed already laravel auth ?

Comment: yes! its easy in 5.x versions but in 6.x version its quite difficult...

Comment: you already displayed your login page ?

Comment: yes login page is displaying. now i wants to pass some data from login controller to login.blade.php

Comment: @UpasanaChauhan Do you create route in web.php ??

Comment: as i am including header like -> @include(includes.header)

Comment: @HiteshKumar its already created...  Auth::routes();

Comment: @UpasanaChauhan Do you send data from the controller for example - return view('home')->compact('foo');

Comment: class LoginController extends Controller
{

 protected $redirectTo = RouteServiceProvider::HOME;


public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
}
} is my whole logincontroller where should i put the code you shared? @HiteshKumar

Comment: @UpasanaChauhan From which controller you are rendering that view ??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just customize your showLoginForm function provided by laravel as default in your LoginController. see code below

```
class LoginController extends Controller {

   protected $redirectTo = RouteServiceProvider::HOME;

   public function __construct() {
      $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
   }

  public function showLoginForm()
  {
      return view('login', ["data"=> 'this is test data']);
  }
}
```

Comment: Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to learn Laravel, I would recommend checking out the guides in their documentation here: https://laravel.com/docs/6.x

Relating to authentication, there is a short guide here that will get you up and running quickly: https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/authentication

You can use the two commands below to setup all of the framework and routing that you need to handle authentication automatically, it will also give you an idea of what to look at if you choose to build your own authentication in future.

```
composer require laravel/ui --dev

php artisan ui vue --auth
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, there should have a `Trait` named `AuthenticatesUsers` onto the `LoginController.php` in Laravel 6.x. But somehow we don't see it in the login controller you provided above.

The `Trait` is located here

```
vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/AuthenticatesUsers.php
```

However there is a method called `showLoginForm()`. You can override this method and pass whatever you need to pass in as the following.

```
/**
 * Show the application's login form.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function showLoginForm()
{
    // Notice the second argument
    return view('auth.login', ['key' => 'value']);
}
```

Hope this would make sense.